# How to ensure that GPU memory is actually deallocated after an OpenCV T-API function call?

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu

OpenCV's T-API (`UMat`s) is [asynchronous by design](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17789#issuecomment-656614308): tasks run in the background until

- either the result is requested via [`UMat::getMat()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d45/classcv_1_1UMat.html#a3d84c72c06ddd55d35b87c3d222d2674),
- or manual synchronization is invoked via [`cv::ocl::finish()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d83/group__core__opencl.html#gabfca32247f267c662b3bff6587d14b40).

By looking at the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/b698d0a6ee12342a87b8ad739d908fd8d7ff1fca/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp#L5781-L5795), I am under the impression that at least in some cases also memory deallocation is asynchronous. This leads to allocation failures if memory-expensive calls are performed in a loop, even if [`cv::ocl::finish()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d83/group__core__opencl.html#gabfca32247f267c662b3bff6587d14b40) is explicitly invoked. For example:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto const nLoops = 5;
    auto const imageWidth = 46340;  // Image size ~ 2 GiB.

    for (int iLoop = 0; iLoop < nLoops; ++iLoop)
    {
        std::cout << "Loop " << iLoop << " begins.\n";
        {
            // bigImage will be destroyed as soon as it is out of scope.
            auto const bigImage = cv::UMat::zeros(imageWidth, imageWidth, CV_8UC1);
        }
        cv::ocl::finish();
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Success!";
}
```

Here the expensive function is [`cv::UMat::zeros()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d45/classcv_1_1UMat.html#ab846739615683bbd536d90c06c40c47f), I observed an [analogous behavior](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17789) with  [`cv::fastNlMeansDenoising()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d79/group__photo__denoise.html#ga76abf348c234cecd0faf3c42ef3dc715).

Running the above example with

- OpenCV 4.1.1
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 with 4 GiB RAM, ~3.3 GiB available for OpenCL.
- NVIDIA driver version 446.14
- Visual Studio 2019 16.6.5
- Windows 10 64 bit

I get

```
Loop 0 begins.
[ INFO:0] global C:\tools\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\src\4.1.1-fb9e10326a.clean\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp (888) cv::ocl::haveOpenCL Initialize OpenCL runtime...
[ INFO:0] global C:\tools\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\src\4.1.1-fb9e10326a.clean\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp (430) cv::ocl::OpenCLBinaryCacheConfigurator::OpenCLBinaryCacheConfigurator Successfully initialized OpenCL cache directory: C:\Users\ANGELO~1.PER\AppData\Local\Temp\opencv\4.1\opencl_cache\
[ INFO:0] global C:\tools\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\src\4.1.1-fb9e10326a.clean\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp (454) cv::ocl::OpenCLBinaryCacheConfigurator::prepareCacheDirectoryForContext Preparing OpenCL cache configuration for context: NVIDIA_Corporation--GeForce_GTX_1050--446_14

Loop 1 begins.
OpenCL error CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE (-4) during call: clEnqueueNDRangeKernel('set', dims=2, globalsize=11776x46344x1, localsize=NULL) sync=false
OpenCV(4.1.1) Error: Unknown error code -220 (OpenCL error CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE (-4) during call: clEnqueueReadBuffer(q, handle=000001C44EA8A970, CL_TRUE, 0, sz=2147395600, data=000001C491D93080, 0, 0, 0)) in cv::ocl::OpenCLAllocator::map, file C:\tools\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\src\4.1.1-fb9e10326a.clean\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp, line 5089
OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:
OpenCV(4.1.1) Error: Unknown error code -220 (OpenCL error CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE (-4) during call: clEnqueueReadBuffer(q, handle=000001C44EA8A970, CL_TRUE, 0, sz=2147395600, data=000001C491D93080, 0, 0, 0)) in cv::ocl::OpenCLAllocator::map, file C:\tools\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\src\4.1.1-fb9e10326a.clean\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp, line 5089
```

A hacky workaround is to allocate a small `UMat` after the call to [`cv::ocl::finish()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d83/group__core__opencl.html#gabfca32247f267c662b3bff6587d14b40): if I understand correctly, the cleanup queue [is flushed](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/b698d0a6ee12342a87b8ad739d908fd8d7ff1fca/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp#L4652) during `UMat` allocation.

```cpp
[…]
        }
        cv::ocl::finish();
        // It seems that an allocation flushes the cleanup queue!
        auto const cleanupQueueFlusher = cv::UMat::zeros(1, 1, CV_8UC1);
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
[…]
```

Output:

```
Loop 0 begins.
[ INFO:0] global C:\tools\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\src\4.1.1-fb9e10326a.clean\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp (888) cv::ocl::haveOpenCL Initialize OpenCL runtime...
[ INFO:0] global C:\tools\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\src\4.1.1-fb9e10326a.clean\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp (430) cv::ocl::OpenCLBinaryCacheConfigurator::OpenCLBinaryCacheConfigurator Successfully initialized OpenCL cache directory: C:\Users\ANGELO~1.PER\AppData\Local\Temp\opencv\4.1\opencl_cache\
[ INFO:0] global C:\tools\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\src\4.1.1-fb9e10326a.clean\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp (454) cv::ocl::OpenCLBinaryCacheConfigurator::prepareCacheDirectoryForContext Preparing OpenCL cache configuration for context: NVIDIA_Corporation--GeForce_GTX_1050--446_14

Loop 1 begins.

Loop 2 begins.

Loop 3 begins.

Loop 4 begins.

Success!
```

What is the proper / official / API-provided way to make sure that unused memory is actually deallocated after a T-API function call?

Relevant [GitHub issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17789). Cross-posted on the [OpenCV forum](https://forum.opencv.org/t/338).